# Firefox 3.5 "hangs" when rendering TABLE

Tags: html, performance, html-table, firefox-3

I have a simple HTML Table (10 columns x 500 rows).  When the page loads I start to scroll down and the browser hangs, and won't allow me to scroll for 3-5 seconds.  This usually happens around row 75-100.  Sometimes I have to scroll all the way to the bottom, and start scrolling back up to the top.  Either way, it is rare that I don't experience this behavior at all.

I have tried this in IE, Safari and Firefox 2, all have absolutely no problem.  I know it is not due to server-side processing, network latency, or client-side script.  I have tried setting CSS table-layout to "fixed" with no apparent result.  The content of the table's cells are plain text, no images, etc.

I am left to believe it is a performance issue introduced in Firefox 3.x.  Does anyone know of a fix (and no, downgrading to Firefox 2, or using pagination, etc. is not an option)?

Here is the HTML I have (mine uses JSP to build table).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Firefox 3.x Table Rendering Performance Issue</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;">
            <tbody>
            <% for (int r=0; r<500; r++) { %>
                <tr><% for (int c=0; c<10; c++) { %><td><%=r%>-<%=c%></td><% } %></tr>
            <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a known bug - https://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=sq&comments_parentId=394490&forumId=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Chetan Sastry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31284/chetan-sastry) notes, this is consistent with a known bug, [listed in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504987).

Apparently, this is due to deep regression during saving of session data.  The [workaround is to disable saving of session data](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.sessionstore.privacy_level) by going to `about:config` and set `Browser.sessionstore.privacy_level` to 2 (which means no session data will be saved).

To make this programming-related: you might consider working with the Mozilla crew to fix this!

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I searched Google for over an hour looking for any information regarding this.  I appreciate your help!